# php парсинг vk foaf

Tags: php, xml, вконтакте, xpath

Каким способом возможно спарсить данные по ссылке https://vk.com/foaf.php?id=1 ? Мне необходимо получить строчку с датой регистрации во ВКонтакте ya:created dc:date="2006-09-23T20:27:12+03:00". Может кто-нибудь написать как это делается, ибо в интернете не нашел четкого ответа?

Comment: @wnull попробовал как было показано в этой теме, но у меня вместо вывода - чистый белый лист, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: "Телепаты в отпуске".